# How to make a delete button delete a specific post?

Tags: python, html, django

I have this delete button with a dialog on it but the button does not get the post right and I think it always starts to delete from the first post so I end up deleting them all also my template does not even gets the correct title of the post even though I'm using the same tag why is that? it always gets the title of the first post and deletes only that not the one I click on I will appreciate your help

views.py

```html
@login_required()
def delete(request, id):
     poost = get_object_or_404(post, pk=id)
     if request.user == poost.author:
          poost.delete()
          messages.error(request, f'Post deleted!')
          return redirect("/")
```

post.html (where my delete dialog and button is)

```html
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Are you sure?</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="text-muted"> Do you really want to delete {{ post.title }}? This process cannot be undone.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <a href="{% url 'delete' post.id %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<div class="container" style="min-height: 100vh; width: 100%;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg 3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div style="margin-top: 60px"></div>
         <div class="card-deck text-center">
            <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
            <div class="card-header" id="linkilink">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal" style="font-family: Georgia, serif; font-size: 25px;">{{post.title}}</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body" style="margin-top: 20px">
          {{ post.body|truncatewords_html:30 }}
          <hr>
          <p> <a><img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" width="75" height="75"></a> <div style="color: rgb(133, 131, 131);">Author:<a href="{% url 'user_posts' post.author.username %}"> {{ post.author }} </a></div> </p>

          
                    <a href="{% url 'detail' post.id %}" class="btn btn-info btn-small" id="readbutton">Read More <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-three-dots" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M3 9.5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm5 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm5 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3z"/>
                      </svg></a>
                      


                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    {% if user == post.author%}
                    
                    <a href="{% url 'update' post.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" >Edit</a>

                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-small" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" >Delete <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                      <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6Z"/>
                      <path d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1ZM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118ZM2.5 3h11V2h-11v1Z"/>
                    </svg></a>

                      {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
    

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

urls.py

```html
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import PostUpdateView


urlpatterns = [
    path('new', views.new, name='new'),
    path('<int:id>', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('delete/<int:id>', views.delete, name='delete'),
    path('search/', views.search_post, name='search-view'),
    path('menu/',views.side_bar, name='menu'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(success_url="/"), name='update'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your view like to below code.

```
@login_required()
def delete(request, id):
     poost = get_object_or_404(pk=id)
     if request.user == poost.author:
          poost.delete()
          messages.error(request, f'Post deleted!')
          return redirect("/")
```

Or to make it more shorter.
Use as below.

```
@login_required()
def delete(request, id):
     poost = get_object_or_404(author=request.user, pk=id)
     poost.delete()
     messages.error(request, f'Post deleted!')
     return redirect("/")
```